# Adding a Delay Ltspice

Tags: ltspice, small-signal

Is it possible to set a delay between two components on Ltspice ? Actually I just want to simulate the time for a sensor it takes to react (set an output) to an exciting signal.

This is for taking into account the impact of a delay with respect to the stability of the system into an AC simulation.

Have a nice day !

Comment: It's not going to work for AC analysis.

Comment: This sounds exciting, ;) what frequency is the delay supposed to occur or Q which determines BW or is it an “all pass” delay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You'd use the delay line element for that, or you can use a [behavioral voltage source `BV`](http://ltwiki.org/?title=B_sources_%28complete_reference%29) and use the behavioral `delay` function in it, for example:

```
SYMBOL bv 128 128 R0
SYMATTR InstName DLY1
SYMATTR Value V=delay(V(x),100n)
```

This element introduces a 100ns delay.

See [this thread](https://www.electronicspoint.com/forums/threads/lt-spice-model-for-a-delay-line.42954/) for discussion of various ways of adding delays in LTspice in general.

Comment: I'm a bit partial to using a lossless transmission line to accomplish this, but the `delay()` function in a B-source is probably much easier to implement.